# Show that $\gcd(n!+1, (n+1)!+1)=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I attempted to solve with induction.

Basis: $\gcd(3,7)=1$, correct.

Let it be true for $n$. I need to show that $\gcd((n+1)!+1, (n+2)!+1)=1$. I see that one of the elements, $(n+1)!+1$, is the same as the one in $\gcd(n!+1, (n+1)!+1)=1$. Then I tried to make $(n+2)!+1$ equal to $n!+1$ by adding $k[(n+1)!+1]$ to $(n+2)!+1$. (examined some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$).

Couldn't get anywhere. Can I prove it this way or do I need a new approach?

Comment: I would use a different approach.  Think about [Euclid's algorithm](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Euclid.shtml) and variations for actually computing the GCD.  I don't think straight induction on the statement is particularly advantageous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Induction is not the right tool. Start by considering $(n+1)(n!+1)-((n+1)!+1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Induction with factorials does not work nicely here; instead, suppose that there is a prime $p>1$ such that $p\mid\gcd(n!+1, (n+1)!+1)$. Then $p$ divides $$(n+1)!+1-(n!+1)=(n+1)!-n!=n\cdot n!,$$ so $p\mid n$ or $p\mid n!$. In every case, $p\mid n!$, and since $p\mid n!+1$, we get that $p\mid 1$, which is a contradiction.